# Как же обособляется словосочетание "в смысле"?

Tags: пунктуация

Я так понял, что "в смысле" обособляется по решению автора. Нужно ли ставить какой-либо знак в конкретных примерах перед или после "в смысле"? Может, двоеточие?

1. Пример из передачи "ДаЁшь молодЁжь" :

> - Ну ты красава, Ржавый!
> - В смысле красава?
> - В смысле ты вчера тому лохозавру круто вломил!

2. 

> - Как дела в остальном?
> - В смысле в остальном?
> - В смысле "на личном фронте".

Согласно "Словарю вводных слов и словосочетаний Остроумовой О. А. и Фрамполь О.Д."

В СМЫСЛЕ 1, наречие; разг.
Употребляется в функции вводного при желании говорящего найти в процессе речи наиболее подходящее выражение:
Ночью на станциях слышно, как переговариваются какие-то железнодорожники, в смысле, громкоговорители чего-то говорят, громко, гулко, и ничего не разобрать (Е.Гришковец).

В СМЫСЛЕ 2, союз; разг.
Невводное, употребляется в функции пояснительного союза (= то есть), не обособляется:
Сидите в своем городе, в своем доме, в своем времени, в смысле в своей эпохе, и смотрите фильм про какую-то Французскую революцию (Е.Гришковец); А там - западня, в смысле вражеская эскадра (Е.Гришковец); Прошу, в смысле умоляю, катись отсюда (Д.Гранин).

В СМЫСЛЕ 3 чего-л., предлог; разг.
Невводное, оборот с предлогом в смысле употребляется в функции обстоятельства образа действия, не обособляется*:
Но в смысле сборов они значительно отстали от «Амфитриона» (М.Булгаков); Эта манера на Моисеенко действовала в смысле усиления того особенного и впечатления, и уважения, и обаяния, какое он чувствовал к ней (Н.Гарин-Михайловский).
Обособляется при желании автора придать обороту особую значимость, интонационно выделяется:
Его безукоризненной, в смысле костюма, внешности дико противоречила пьяная судорога лица (А.Грин); Вообще, конечно, Нюрка - баба справная и видная из себя, но и я ведь тоже еще молодой, обсмотреться надо сперва что к чему, а потом уж и обзаводиться по закону, в смысле семейной жизни (В.Войнович).

Так как же все-таки выделять это словосочетание?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну ты красава, Ржавый!
В смысле красава ?
В смысле, ты вчера тому лохозавру круто вломил!

Как дела в остальном ?
В смысле в остальном ?
В смысле, "на личном фронте"

1) Вводные слова поясняют сказанное ранее, обособляются запятой или тире

Бегаем там, бомбочки взрываем, ну в смысле ― хлопушки. Это правильно. В смысле, тоже правильно. Да и фильм ― женский, в смысле, именно женщина может его понять.В общем, дети ― это звери. В смысле ― всё чуют.

2) Наречие на обособляется, говорящий сразу уточняет смысл

В смысле зрелищности больше повезло болельщикам Рима.   А как у них в смысле учёбы?

3) В смЫсле красава ? (В какОм смысле я красава?).

В приведенных выражениях запятая НЕ СТАВИТСЯ, они являются сленговыми по своей неполной (укороченной) структуре, где для большей выразительности ударение с отсутствующего вопросительного слова перенесено на предмет.

Answer (score 4):

Ваши примеры ("В смысле красава", "в смысле в остальном" и пр.) суть не что иное, как молодёжный сленг. Здесь "в смысле" – это не пояснительный союз, и не предлог, и не вводное слово, а что-то вроде "почему" (почему красава?) или "как" (как в остальном?) и т.п. Создаётся впечатление, что люди стыдится признаться, что они чего-то не поняли. Такие вещи, думаю, грамматику интересовать не должны. Можно считать их чисто разговорными (и к тому же неряшливыми, малограмотными)

Answer (score 4):

Везде без запятой:
В смысле "красава"? - В каком смысле "красава"?
В смысле ты вчера тому лохозавру круто вломил! - То есть ты вчера тому...
В смысле "в остальном"? - В каком смысле (что значит) "в остальном"?
В смысле "на личном фронте". - То есть "на личном фронте".