# Какая пунктуация вокруг "в смысле"? Это же всегда конкретно, из контекста?

Tags: пунктуация, выбор-слов

Был вопрос: **[Как же обособляется словосочетание “в смысле”?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/417023/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5)**

Ну и ответы мне не ответили...

> Люди эти всегда “правильные”, в смысле, достойные уважения.

Я бы поправила так (но не уверена):

Люди эти всегда “правильные”, в смысле - достойные уважения.

Comment: [Повтор вопроса](http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/417023/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b6%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bc%d1%8b%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это пояснительный оборот,  обычно "в смысле" отделяют запятыми, почему-то приравнивая к вводным. Я не воспринимаю "в смысле" как вводное, это разговорное вместо "то есть", после него нет знаков.

Тире возможно как авторское, ну вот после "главное" ставят же тире, и мне нравится с тире.

Хочется вообще сам смысл пояснения сделать условным и взять в кавычки, но это тоже авторское. Здесь вообще всё авторское, потому что разговорное, не литературное:

Люди эти всегда “правильные”, в смысле  "достойные уважения".

Comment: Пожалуйста, у туточки http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/431142/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8/431153#431153 и у тамочки http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/431184/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE